# Insert new lines before first occurrence of an option string - unix

Tags: string, unix, sed, insert

Initial file:

```
BEGIN SUBRECORD
         Name "New_value"
         Prompt "New_value"
         Default "$PROJDEF"
         ListValues "$PROJDEF\(9)Overwrite"
END SUBRECORD 
MetaBag "CMetaProperty"
............
................
.................
MetaBag "CMetaProperty"
.................
.............
............
MetaBag "CMetaProperty"
```

Expected output: I want to add new lines before the first occurrence of string `MetaBag "CMetaProperty"` and have:

```
BEGIN SUBRECORD
         Name "New_value"
         Prompt "New_value"
         Default "$PROJDEF"
         ListValues "$PROJDEF\(9)Overwrite"
END SUBRECORD
BEGIN SUBRECORD
         Name "Variable"
         Prompt "Variable"
         Default "$PROJDEF"
         ListValues "$PROJDEF\(9)Overwrite"
END SUBRECORD
MetaBag "CMetaProperty"
............
................
.................
MetaBag "CMetaProperty"
.................
.............
............
MetaBag "CMetaProperty"
```

I tried using sed command, but the new lines are inserted before all occurrence
s of my option string.

```
sed  '/MetaBag "CMetaProperty"/ i       BEGIN SUBRECORD\n         Name "Variable"\n         Prompt "Variable"\n         Default "$PROJDEF"\n         ListValues "$PROJDEF\(9)Overwrite"\n      END SUBRECORD' infile.txt
```

How can i modify the command?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /MetaBag/ && $0 !~ /^MetaBag/) gsub( /MetaBag/ , "\n&", $0)}1'
```

`$0 ~ /MetaBag/` <-- Check if line contains **MetaBag**
`$0 !~ /^MetaBag/` <-- Check if record is not starting with  **MetaBag**
`gsub( /MetaBag/ , "\n&", $0)` <-- Replace MetaBag with new line + MetaBag

Demo:

```
$cat test.tst
BEGIN SUBRECORD
         Name "New_value"
         Prompt "New_value"
         Default "$PROJDEF"
         ListValues "$PROJDEF\(9)Overwrite"
END SUBRECORD *MetaBag "CMetaProperty"*
............
................
.................
MetaBag "CMetaProperty"
.................
.............
............
MetaBag "CMetaProperty" 

$awk '{if($0 ~ /MetaBag/ && $0 !~ /^MetaBag/) gsub( /MetaBag/ , "\n&", $0)}1' test.tst
BEGIN SUBRECORD
         Name "New_value"
         Prompt "New_value"
         Default "$PROJDEF"
         ListValues "$PROJDEF\(9)Overwrite"
END SUBRECORD *
MetaBag "CMetaProperty"*
............
................
.................
MetaBag "CMetaProperty"
.................
.............
............
MetaBag "CMetaProperty" 

$
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and cat):

```
<<\! sed -e '/MetaBag/{e cat -' -e ':a;n;ba}' file
Lines of text to insert
    before the first occurrence 
    of the string `MetaBag`

!
```

Following the inserted string(s) the sed invocation reads/prints the remainder of the file.

The string(s) to be inserted are placed in a here-document and on matching the regexp `/MetaBag/` sed evaluates `cat -` which accepts the here-document as stdin and passes it straight out as stdout when the `e` command is executed. The sed script then runs a loop that prints the current line in the pattern space and replaces by the next line and then repeats to the end of the file.

N.B. The `e` command evaluates the commands following it, and these command must end in a newline (or its equivalent). The `-e` option does this by default and hence the script is split in two to accommodate this.

Comment: at first glance is working. thanks! can you please explain me the command?

Comment: also, how should i modify it in case I want to have instead MetaBag a parameter?

Comment: @MathewLinton you can replace `MetaBag` by `'"$param"'` however any meta characters such as `^$.*&[]/\ ` within the parameter, should be escaped/quoted by placing a ` \ ` in front of them.